# Changing Permissions on a live *.mdw file?

Tags: vba, security, ms-access

If I write code [like the following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697130/changing-mdw-permissions-in-ms-access-using-sql) to change permissions / add users an `*.mdw` file; can I run that code while the `*.mdw` file is live?  Another words while people are still using it?

I'm using MS-Access 2003.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. And '*.mdw' file is in fact mdb database. Changes to 'Users' and 'Groups' collections are written there at once.